# LaTeX for Graph Theory?

Tags: graphics

What should I use to make Graphs for Graph Theory in LaTeX?

I have seen a lot of stuff about tkz (specifically `tkz-berge`), but I'm running Ubuntu and there is no package for it, that I can tell. Trying to download all the .sty's is confusing the bejesus out of me. I cannot even find all the dependencies for `tkz-graph`.

Comment: As an Ubuntu user sadly one has to do some manual installing for many packages because only texlive 2009 ships with ubuntu and not the 2010 version. However, I'd recommend you to be a bit adventurous and install packages manually. tkz-graph is, i believe, the same as tkz-euclide and can be found here: http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/index.html You may want to get a new version of tikz too, it can be found here: http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/. Use the search function to find out how to manually install packages

Comment: Moved tkz.zip into /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tkz and also put the tkz-graph,tkz-berge,tkz-arith.sty's and also dl'ed pgf and place in the generic folder. Now, I get a pgf math error when I try to make examples. I guess I installed something wrong? Work on it tomorrow.

Comment: I'd actually recommend to just skip the Ubuntu/Debian packages and install TeX Live directly from http://tug.org/texlive/. That's easier than installing lots of packages by hand and makes it easy to keep up to date.

Comment: The Ubuntu packaged version of texlive is pretty good for the basics, but the more you dig into it, the less satisfactory it becomes until one day you decide you have to uninstall it and install tl2010 for yourself... I'm just trying to find a time when I don't have several half written documents I need to finish so I can take the time to do it...

Comment: Sorry but you can't use the old tkz-berge and tkz-arith inside tkz with tkz-euclide. I wrote a new version of some arithmetic tools for the tkz packages and tkz-berge use these tools. I try  to send all my packages on the servers of CTAN. Now I work to update tkz-berge but I need to adapt the packages with the  pgf CVS version because some of  my tools are now inside pgf. Well, I have a lot of works with all theses packages, so you need to be patient. I will make a new version of tkz-berge for the CTAN in some days.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This perhaps isn't quite the answer you were looking for as it isn't TeX-centric, but [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) has always been (for me) **the** tool for drawing any kind graph with more then three vertices. The ability to export to PS or PDF is a plus and there are tons of wrappers so you can use your language of choice (personally I use [pydot](http://dkbza.org/pydot.html)). `Graphviz` shines when you have many vertices that you would like to be arranged according to some pattern (several are provided).

That being said, for small graphs (or those with a tree-like dependency), nothing can beat `tikz` with the iteration of TeX directly into the document, though the verbosity sometimes is off putting.

Example of a simple `tikz` graph code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->]
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt]
  \node[vertex] (G_1) at (-1,-1) {1};
  \node[vertex] (G_2) at (0,0)   {2};
  \node[vertex] (G_3) at (1,-1)  {3};
  \draw (G_1) -- (G_2) -- (G_3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can even write graphviz right in your tex doc with [dot2texi](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dot2texi/dot2texi.pdf), but you have to use --shel-escape when compiling with pdflatex. I actually prefer just using one of the graphviz tools (dot, neato, et al) and embedding it.

Comment: I asked a similar question recently regarding drawing chemical connectivity graphs, and insomuch as automatic node placement is concerned, GraphViz really seems to be the way to go, as PGF/TikZ requires explicit node placement, relative or absolute. When dealing with a large graph (or even a small one) automatic placement is pretty much necessary if you want something half-way appealing that isn't a tree or a grid. `neato` is fantastic as it carries out a balls-and-springs 'energy minimisation' of sorts to generate optimised node positioning.

Comment: When I use Graphviz, I always import the graphs as a TikZ image using `dot2tex --codeonly --usepdflatex --tikzedgelabels --styleonly -t raw -f tikz graph.dot > graph.tikz`.  `dot2tex` is available here: http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/.  This allows one to include TeX markup in the graph node/edge labels.

Comment: Ended up using this. It was probably over kill considering my graph had only 6 vertices, but it wasn't that bad.

Answer (score 10):

I'm the author of tkz-graph and tkz-berge. These packages are removed from my sites altermundus.fr and altermundus.com because I work actually to update them and to adapt them to pgf 2.0 and 2.1.
I use some arithmetic tools and now these tools are in pgf 2.1 so it's better for me to update all the packages. 
There are also actually some problems of compatibility with my new packages tkz-base and euclide. If you want to use old versions of tkz-berge, don't install tkz-base. Problems come from arithmetic functions in tkz-arith and pgfmath. You can use my email from my site if you want an old version  adapted to pgf 2.1

Comment: I thought that was probably why they were not up. I really want to use tkz-berge, but this time I went with dot and dot2tex. Once the new one is up though, I will definitely try it

Answer (score 3):

`pgf` is in the Ubuntu repositories, so for that you only need `sudo apt-get install pgf`.
You do not need the newest version of tikz to use `tkz-graph`.
Then create a directory in your home folder, say `~/texmf/tex/latex/tkz`, and put
`tkz-graph.sty`, `tkz-arith.sty` and `tkz-berge.sty` there. This should be enough. I have some examples of the usage of `tkz-berge` in my blog: http://graphtheoryinlatex.wordpress.com

Comment: I have been using your blog for tests to see if my install worked :) sadly not working yet but i will try to just do only what your said and see if it works

Comment: I tried what you said and got some stuff working. I don't know if I found an old tkz-graph/arith/berge but it will complain about "\grCirculant" and a PGF math error "unkown function modl."

Comment: Yes I've seen some times that `\grCirculant` misbehaves. In those cases I would just draw a `\grCycle` and then use `\EdgeInGraphMod` for the other edges. Hopefully Alain will release an updated version to CTAN soon.

Comment: @Buttink: you can find the new version of tkz-graph and tkz-berge here : http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/index.html and I put some examples for tkz-graph here : http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/graph/index.html and for tkz-berge : http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/berge/index.html. There is also a document about Named Graphs. You need to wait some days if you want to see these packages on CTAN.

Answer (score 3):

I hear that a lot of graph theory people use [Ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/).  I am not a graph theorist, but I use Ipe, and I can see how the snapping modes of Ipe would make graph creation pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

I like metapost - it combines with latex very easily (you can use latex to enter the text on the graph so that fount sizes are consistent) and you can program the elements of the graph exactly how you want (Including recursively).

www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf

Note to get metapost to play with latex you often need to define

> export TEX=latex

before you run the mpost command.  It took me a while to find that out.

Also note: be careful about adding the above command to your .bashrc or you can get very strange errors when generating docs with texi (took me even longer to discover this).